# display records from database in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem displaying data in grid view I am a new learner of asp.net please help me. My code is below:
Problem is:

## DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'news_id'.

.aspx

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="international_news"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="news_id">                       
               <Columns>
                     <asp:BoundField  DataField="news_id" Visible="false"/>
                   <asp:BoundField  DataField="news_title"/>                            
                       <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="ReadMore" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("news_id")%>'>
                            Read More
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>                    
                    </Columns>        
                </asp:GridView>
```

======================================================================================

.aspx.cs

```
 con.Open();
            string sqlString = "SELECT [news_id], [news_title] from upload_news";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, con);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {

                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("News Title", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("News ID", typeof(string))});
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr[1].ToString() != "yes")
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }


            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("News Title", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("News ID", typeof(string))});
```

in

```
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("news_title", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("news_id", typeof(string))});
```